# "Seem all to" vs. "all seem to"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> The men seem all to understand the situation.
>
> The men all seem to understand the situation.

Both "seem all to" and "all seem to" can be frequently found on the Internet, with the latter being way more popular. Are they both correct? Does both mean the same? Is one preferred?

Comment: Both are idiomatic, and as you observe the second is more popular. The former would perhaps be associated with a more elegantly spoken individual, but such a person might equally employ the latter too. That would be the case in Britain, but may be quite different elsewhere.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say the first one. Sounds odd to me.

Comment: I'm with Nigel, and I suspect the former might once, long ago have been associated with a more elegantly spoken individual but today and for at least a generation before, it's simply archaic.

Comment: I've also never heard the first form, but in addition to formality, it might be regional.